# How to remove side panel in Ubuntu when viewing my Activities?

Tags: gnome, customization, dconf

I am a beginner in Linux and have installed the GNOME shell and dconf editor. I was exploring the customization features in Linux and somehow, when I press on the windows key or the "Activities" button in the top left corner, I get two bar panels. How do I remove the one that's on the left?

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Dash to dock extension. Have you installed this extension? It seems there is a bug. When dock is installed it should hide the right side one.

Comment: it is installed indeed. However, when I deactivate this extension, it does not fix the problem

Comment: Press ALT + F2, then in the dialogue that appears input `r` and press Enter. This will restart Gnome and might fix the problem.

Comment: it says restart is not available on Wayland

Comment: In Wayland.. logout and login is required. What is the version of dash to dock extension??

Comment: it is version 69. I think i will switch to KDE plasma rather than gnome shell if that's what might cause the problem

Comment: I have logged out and logged back in...still doesn't work. I think it's a bug from the extension itself

Comment: How did you install dash to dock extension? from Ubuntu repository or direct from gnome extensions site?

Comment: I think from the site if i remember correctly. I don't have this problem anymore though because I had to reinstall ubuntu since it crashed.